# Sharepoint search, redirect from OSSSearchResults.aspx to Search centre

Tags: sharepoint, search

i have a question about configuration fo search pages in sharepoint. There are two types of searches:

1. contextual which searches just in current page or list (they are labelled like:  This site: Name of site or This list: Name of list), they point to OSSSearchResults.aspx page
2. custom searches which can be user defined, they point to Search center

Custom searches are not a problem, since search center can be modified easily, but with contextual searches there is a problem.

So, is there a way to configure sharepoint so it will send users to search center even with contextual searches?

I know that i can insert some javascript into OSSSearchResults.aspx or create HttpHandler which will redirect him automatically, but i wonder if there is some more native solution.

Comment: This is your ultimate solution:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16829/redirect-search-to-search-results-aspx/35301#35301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [an article](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2008/11/configuring-scopes-dropdown/) that might help you configure this.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePOint 2013
 - Go to site settings-> Seach settings -> Enter the search center url-> tick mark the ->  Use the same results page settings as my parent.

- Configure Search Navigation:
- Everything -> /sites/searchcenter/Pages/results.aspx

Hope this helped