# Remove scope dropdown from OSSSearchResults.aspx in SharePoint MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, search, moss

When searching in SharePoint the results are returned to a page called OSSSearchResults.aspx.

This page has a scope dropdown for the search i.e. Site:Departments

How can I remove this scope so that the whole site collection is always searching, irrespective of the site I am within?

All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can disable contextual scope via Sharepoint's configuration. I had similar problem, which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325757/sharepoint-search-redirect-from-osssearchresults-aspx-to-search-centre). Im my case I needed to redirect from OSSSearchResults page to Search center or just disable those scopes which redirect to this page. Sample of configuration with some explanation can be found [here](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2008/11/configuring-scopes-dropdown/)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Trys some simple Javascript to set the value and dynamically hide the drop down. Job done!

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var objDDL = document.getElementById("ctl00_g_edb49d82_8042_45e7_b0f7_2fa3fbed4ae6_SBScopesDDL");
if( objDDL ) {
    objDDL.selectedIndex = 0;
    objDDL.style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply inherit this class from core.css into your theme:

SELECT.ms-searchbox{
        visibility:hidden;
}

Then the select will be gone.

Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

This is the search page of Windows SharePoint Services V3.0 search and it is pretty much set in stone. It is not as flexible as a MOSS 2007 search center where you can customize the search web parts, search scopes and much more. WSS search only allows you to search single sites and sub-sites. Cross site search is not supported - you will need an Enterprise Search solution to do that.

Now, I guess you do not want or need to invest in MOSS 2007. But you could consider setting up a new Search Server 2008 Express (free) next to your WSS server. This gives you Enterprise search capabilities at a low cost. Let the MSS 2008 index all your WSS site collections and let the users search from a search center site on the MSS 2008 server.

One downside, however, is the small search box on your WSS sites will still point to the OSSSearchResults.aspx page. You will need to install another search box to direct users to the MSS 2008 search center.

Comment: Hey Lars

We are actually running MOSS 2007, so does that affect your answer?

Thanks Again

Comment: Ah, I see. The "This Site" scope is not supported by a MOSS 2007 search center. But you can unfortunately not remove the scope from the drop-down. Only option I know of is the SearchResultPageURL property in the SearchArea.xml file.

Comment: You can find the SearchArea.xml file here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\OSearchBasicFeature

Comment: I would recommend to let the MOSS 2007 search scope "All Sites" be the default scope and then hide the drop-down in the small search box. This way all queries go to the MOSS 2007 search center. The DD can be hidden by changing the DropDownMode property in the SearchArea.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the file directly, although this is not a recommended practice. The file is found in `\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\osssearchresults.aspx` and the control in question is in line 97:

```
<SPSWC:SearchBoxEx id="SearchBox" runat="server" 
          GoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif" 
          GoImageUrlRTL="/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif" 
          DropdownModeEx=ShowDD_DefaultURL
          ScopeDisplayGroupName = ""
          FrameType="None" 
          ShouldTakeFocusIfEmpty=true />
```